# Loading page through ajax or jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one main page in which I am loading content of another page, I can do it perfectly without any concern, but for this I have two options one is by using puring jquery and another is with ajax, can you please tell me which function should be used in which condition or what is the difference between two as both are ok.

My html page is as under:

```
 <! doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hwcb.css">
</head>
<body>
     <p> <input type="button" value="Load" class="l1"/>
       <div class="la1"></div>
  <p></br>

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/css.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My jquery functions is as under:

```
$('.l1').click(function(){$('.la1').load('test1.php');});
```

Another function which also works is as under:

```
$('l1').click(function(){
$.ajax({
url:'test1.php',
success:function(data){
$('.la1').html(data);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load()` is a shorthand method of `$.ajax()`

So, literally there's no difference or contradiction between them, `.load()` is internally calling `.ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

Both do the same request and deliver the same payload. The difference is that ajax() and similar allow more fine grained reaction on what is going on: reaction on errors, post processing of the payload, other things to do with the payload than just loading it into a element.